# CiviEvent with Stripe payments: 60% of payment attempts don't have any customer details

Tags: civievent, payment-processor, stripe, online-registration

We have CiviEvent online registrations with online payments through Stripe. 40% of the registrations work just fine, but 60% of them fail. Checking in Stripe tells me that they are **missing all customer details!** How can that happen? How do I troubleshoot this?

We are using latest WordPress and latest CiviCRM 5.68.0 with latest Stripe extension. All is up to date and we see no warnings in the system console.

***Update:** We contacted Stripe Support for help on this, and they say they've passed it on internally and would report back. They still have no update for us, but all of these blocked transactions have magically disappeared. I have no explanation.*

[image]